# Calculate the coordinates upper right corner from the center

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster

How do i calculate the coordinates upper right corner from the coordinates of center? if there's an example that would be really helpful.

Comment: If you edit the question to provide the data you have, the example could use your values.  It would also help if you specified which "center" (UR pixel center or raster center).

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE. Could you please elaborate a bit more about what you are trying to do? (The thread _["How to frame a good question?"](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3349/how-to-frame-a-good-question)_ is definitely a helpful guideline.) In addition to @Vince's comment, you would at least need some information about the specific raster resolution and about its projection to perform such a calculation.

Comment: i do not need it to be implemented on the application i needed it to calculate for my theoretical exam on ArcGIS :)

Answer (score 1):

If you're sure your coordinates are exactly in the center of the cell, you could get the raster cell size using [Get Raster Properties](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//0017000000m7000000) and add 1/2 CELLSIZEX to the X coord and do the same with CELLSIZEY for the Y coord.